# NPM module reference not working for Mongoose

Tags: node.js, heroku, mongoose, npm

So when trying to deploy a Node.js app to Heroku, I am getting this error with heroku logs -t.

```
> State changed from crashed to starting Starting process with command
> `node ./bin/www`  Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per
> process (WEB_MEMORY)  Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1    Error: Cannot
> find module 'mongodb/lib/read_preference'
>      throw err;  module.js:340
>            ^
>      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
>      at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>      at require (module.js:380:17)
>      at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>      at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:5:16)
>      at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>      at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

The folder structure of the file looking for the target file is such (inside the node_modules folder):

```
mongoose/lib/utils.js
```

and the code looking for the file is such:

```
var ReadPref = require('mongodb/lib/read_preference')
```

and the target file is at:

```
mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/read_preference.js
```

Now based on Node's searching algorithm (https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), the file will move up to the node_modules folder and then search for mongodb, find it and enter its folder, finally getting to the read_preference file.  However, this obviously isn't working.  What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Why you say?

Heroku caches your modules, so any updates to package.json won't get recognized.  So your local copy will be blatantly correct; however, Heroku's won't. In order to overcome this, type:

`heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false`

Comment: This isn't accurate. The first step in a heroku install is to restore node_modules from cache; the second step is to run npm install over node_modules to update them to reflect any changes in your package.json or shinkwrap file.

Comment: So what was confusing to me was updating the mongoose npm to 4.x was leading to cannot find module errors.  The references to those modules/files was correct; however, Heroku was throwing these errors.  I am probably wrong as you pointed out, but it seemed like a logical deduction.